# sed for pattern match delete below lines till curly brackets or pattern match

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have dhcp.lease file having following lines

```
lease 192.168.10.15 {
  starts 1 2012/10/26 12:04:54;
  ends 0 2013/01/24 12:04:54;
#shared-network: LAN
  tstp 0 2013/01/24 12:04:54;
  cltt 1 2012/10/26 12:04:54;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 64:a3:cb:44:d5:00;
  uid "\001d\243\313@\333(";
  client-hostname "iPhone56";
}
lease 192.168.10.104 {
  starts 4 2012/08/13 05:20:36;
  ends 5 2013/02/12 05:20:36;
#shared-network: LAN
  tstp 5 2013/02/12 05:20:36;
  cltt 4 2012/08/13 05:20:36;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:27:0e:08:60:88;
  uid "\001\000\014)V\321\222";
  client-hostname "ImageMachine";
}
```

I want to delete line with 192.168.10.15 ip address and below lines till next lease come means I want to delete lines which are related to that lease ip only using sed or awk.

Comment: Please take a look here to make your question more readable: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3):

This simply requires a direct use of `sed` ranges:

```
sed -e '/^lease 192.168.10.15 {$/,/^}$/d'
```

Delete the lines from the one starting `lease` and the IP address and the open brace up to the next line containing only `}`.

You can also do it with `awk`:

```
awk '/^lease 192.168.10.15 {$/,/^\}$/ {next} {print}'
```

For the range(s) of lines from the one starting `lease` and the IP address and the open brace up to the next line containing only '}', do a `{next}` to skip to the next line, without printing it — effectively delete the line.  All other lines get the default operation of `{print}`, which could also be spelled `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command:

```
sed '/192\.168\.10\.15 /{:a;N;/\}/d;ba}' file
```

details:

```
/192\.168\.10\.15 / { # when the ip (+ a space to not match 151,152,...) is found 
    :a;         # define the label "a"
    N;          # append the next line to the pattern space
    /\}/d;      # when a "}" is found, delete the pattern space
    ba          # otherwise, go to the label "a"
}
```

Note that when sed executes the delete command d, the pattern space is wiped and the code restarts with the next line.

*(But Jonathan Leffler script is from far more simple!)*

Comment: That's a complex script for such a simple operation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I always forget to use ranges because I always think `sed` will take the largest range (i.e: the last } of the file), I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple with `awk`:

```
awk '!/192\.168\.10\.15/' RS='}\n' ORS='}\n'
```

I'm using `}<newline>` as input and output record separator. I just need to check if the current record contains the IP of interest.